# How can I capture the entire error response with catchError

Tags: angular, error-handling, next.js, rxjs

I am forcing my application to return a 404 message to test how I am handling that in my UI.

I am using NestJs as my backend API. I have a method to get an organization that looks like this:

```
async findOne(organizationId: string): Promise<Organization> {
    const organization = await this.organizationsRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        id: organizationId,
      },
      relations: ['locations', 'users'],
    });

    if (!organization) {
      throw new NotFoundException(
        `Organization with id ${organizationId} not found.`,
      );
    }

    return organization;
  }
```

In my Angular application, I have an organization service that looks like this. I've pulled the `catchError` [from the docs](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) to make sure I wasn't missing something.

```
getOrganization(organizationId: string): Observable<Organization> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Organization>(
                `${this.baseURL}/v1/organization/${organizationId}`
            )
            .pipe(
                catchError((err) => {
                    console.log(
                        'Handling error locally and rethrowing it...',
                        err
                    );
                    return throwError(err);
                })
            );
    }
```

I can see in my network response I'm getting a 404:

```
{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /v1/organization/26ee00d1-9fd8-4e38-a195-024c11ae0958","error":"Not Found"}
```

Everything *seems* to be working. However, I am struggling to get anything other than

> Cannot GET /v1/organization/26ee00d1-9fd8-4e38-a195-024c11ae0958

```
.pipe(catchError((err: HttpResponse<any>) => {
       console.log('err: ', err);  // Cannot GET...
       return throwError(() => new Error());
    })
);
```

I would like to also (maybe) show the status code. For example:

```
...
catchError((err) => {
  console.log(err) // {statusCode: 404, message: "Cannot GET...}
  console.log(err.statusCode) // 404
  console.log(err.message) // Cannot GET...
});
...
```

Anything other than `err` is returning `undefined`. How can I get "access" to the full response I think I'm getting back?

Comment: Can you check your catchError import?

Comment: `import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: I doubt if your `if (!organization)` block is getting triggered. Because the error message you show from the frontend network tab doesn't seem to match the error message you're sending from within the aforementioned `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: my interceptor is only returning a string consisting of the error message.

It turns out that in my `error.interceptor` file, I am checking for a 401 response so that I can redirect to the login page.

Within my `intercept` method, I am reading the error and returning *just* the message.

```
intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                console.log('catching error: ', err); // getting entire object here

                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.authService.signOut().then(() => {
                        //...
                    });
                }

                const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;  // this is my problem.

                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
```

I feel very, very silly.